# Latex plugin for visual studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, latex

I am looking for a latex plugin for Visual Studio 2010 (preferably free) .

Features it must have:

1. Code folding
2. Syntax highlighting
3. AUTOCOMPLETION
4. Error Handling

Comment: This may be better posed at http://tex.stackexchange.com, but I'd be pretty surprised if _any_ LaTeX VS plugin exists at all.

Comment: i believe latex plugins exist for both netbeans and eclipse. Even VS is an equally good IDE (if not better). I find it pretty reasonable to hope for a latex plugin for vs2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think there is anything available for VS.
As an alternative, I use eclipse with the texlipse plugin. It has all of the features on your list. I do not use windows but ubuntu with eclipse, R, MySQL and Sweave is sufficient to cater for all my data connection, management, manipulation, analytical and reporting needs. All the tools listed are available on Windows with sufficient connectivity to SQLserver with RODBC.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there's anything that comes close to what you want to do. But as far as I know, you can - in principle - use Visual Studio with any programming language. If you have enough time to configure it properly.

You can create your own LaTeX-specific [language service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166570%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Moreover, you would have to create own [build rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsbz6cw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

But since I think that is too much work, I recommend TeXnicCenter, a freeware program that has syntax highlight, autocompletion and error handling. I'm not sure about code folding, but I think it does not have this.

Another freeware is LEd (LaTeX Editor), that should have all the features you like, but as far as I remember, I was not that happy with code completion.

Comment: even i am deeply concerned about really nice code completion. There is a Latex editor called "inlage" that has really nice completion but its not free(alas) .

Comment: yep, inlage seems to support all the questioner wants to have.

Comment: Just wanted to add that TeXnicCenter does support code folding. I think its turned off by default

Answer (score 1):

A good choice for a LaTeX Editor is [TeXWorks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/). You should try it, since there is no LaTeX support for Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried texworks. However i could not get code completion to work . All it does is recognise begin if i type \begin but does not give completion for the arguement of the command. Its completion tends to be virtually useless.

Comment: Did you try typing i.e. "\beTABpiTAB" (TAB is the TAB key)? TeXWorks gives you the complete \begin...\end block. The Completion may be other than you expect, but it is powerful. You can even more use shortcuts, i.e. "bpTAB" gives the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think MS VS has been developed as a programmers 'editor'. Of course it's much more than just an editor, but editing (la)tex files doesn't fit into this model. So it's better not to waste the time and to try other solutions. I suggest open-source Lyx which is available on Linux and Windows (and AFAIK on Mac OS) platforms and easy to use. Just try it while waiting for other (possibly better) answers.

Comment: LyX is not LaTeX, and TeX (and the LaTeX3 programming layer provided by `expl3`) is just as much a programming environment as any other language.  On a positive note, I'm going to see if I can't make such a plugin this weekend.

Comment: @Sean Allred : did you make that plugin ? :)

Comment: @MichaelCorleone I found out that I can't make such a plugin easily---it will take more time to go through the tutorials and such than I have time free; it will have to wait at least until Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code with LaTeX extension is available. It is free of charge as well.