# How to write latex comments in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, latex

I want to write comments in visual studio (2012 ultimate) that contain latex syntax.

There is some plug-in to add to visual studio that will enable me to write comment in latex and then see it as latex (e.g. pop up window when im pressing some key shortcut or moving over the comment with the mouse)?

I found that someone asked it before at:

[Latex plugin for visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195982/latex-plugin-for-visual-studio-2010)

But this didn't help me.

I'm also found this:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e216ec81-730b-4022-8305-25c39eb1f820

But this didn't help me either (I got a message of "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products").

Comment: visual studio 2012 ultimate

Comment: That extension appears to support 2010 only

Comment: This is an old question, but you can (typically) easily modify VS2010 plugin installers to work with VS2012. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14308097/135769 for instructions. They're for a different plugin, but have worked for every VS2010 plugin I've installed in VS2012.

Comment: More info: I successfully modified the plugin installer to work with VS2012. Took about 30 seconds.