# Is it possible to use MS Visual Studio as an IDE for LaTeX users?

Tags: visual-studio, latex, visual-studio-2013

I am a big fan of Microsoft Visual Studio. I like the code folding, auto-completion, auto-formatting, and many more.

I am thinking that it will be good if I can abuse MS Visual Studio as an IDE for LaTeX users. Shortly speaking, is it possible? For the first step, I think making me possible to invoke LaTeX compiler and invoke PDF viewer from within Visual Studio is more than enough. But you can step further by allowing me to use auto-completion, etc.

Is there any idea?

LaTeX editors usually have setting to invoke LaTeX compilers and PDF viewers as follows. It might be useful for you.

[image]

Comment: See also [Latex plugin for visual studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5195982)

Comment: Too bad all the answers refer to VSCode instead of answering the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Studio **Code** (VSC) use extension: "LaTeX Workshop".

On Windows: Install MiKTeX, then over MiKTeX Console install package "latexmk". Finally install Perl http://strawberryperl.com/

PDF gets rebuilt automatically on saving the .tex file with VSC.

For viewing the changing .pdf file in Windows "TeXworks" did work best from multiple viewers tried, because it does not lock the .pdf file against changes and quickly refreshes the view on changing pdf output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. Use Visual Studio Code with LaTeX extension. And it is free of charge.

Comment: Someone down voted this correct answer that did not copy other answer because the other one came long after mine.