# How to create a custom shortcut made from several shortcuts in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

I often use the following shortcut in Visual Studio 2017 after typing some code.

```
ctrl+K, ctrl+D          to reformat the alignment

ctrl+R, ctrl+G          to remove and sort the using directive

ctrl+S                  to save
```

It will be more convenient if I can create a single shortcut to do all these 3 jobs. Is it possible in VS 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call several VS commands from a [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) command and assign a single shortcut to it:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.RemoveAndSort");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveSelectedItems");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a bit out of topic. Is it possible to use your extension for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572105/is-it-possible-to-use-ms-visual-studio-as-an-ide-for-latex-users ?